# Calling API through Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to get the values of parameter by calling REST API. I need to fetch the parameters from database for which I need to get the value.
How can I pass the parameters from database.

Comment: Please provide us with some insight in what you've tried to get this to work. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Lookup activity to first query your database and get whatever value you want to get. You will be able to access this returned value in the lookup in your next steps. Parameterize your REST API linked service/dataset. You can pass in the value returned by the Lookup activity to this dataset parameter.

First, check if you are using firstRowOnly or your lookup is returning multiple rows. If it is returning multiple rows, you need to keep your next step in a forEach loop.

If your lookup activity is returning two rows, you get the output like shown below.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "enrollment_number": "123445"
        },
        {
        "enrollment_number": "345678"
        }
    ]

}
```

ADF Expression for URL would be this:

RemainingUrl/@{activity(activity_name).output.value.enrollment_number}

Comment: I am doing the same but I am facing the problems while trying to pass the multiple values in web activity rest api url. Kindly let me know how to pass multiple values received through lookup output in url.

Comment: How to you want to add it to the url? 
Can you give me an example of the type of output you are getting from the Lookup and an example of the kind of url you are trying to form?

Comment: I am adding it by using the syntax @{activity(activity_name).output.value. It is picking entire result in url instead of just the value. for example, from the previous lookup activity I am fetching the enrollment_number, so it is adding enrollment_number along with *********** number. However, I am suppose to pass the enrollment number value only.

Comment: First, check if you are using firstRowOnly or your lookup is returning multiple rows. If it is returning multiple rows, you need to keep your next step in a forEach loop.

If your lookup activity is returning two rows, you get the output like shown below.

{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "enrollment_number": "123445"
        },
        {
        "enrollment_number": "345678"
        }
}

ADF Expression for URL would be this:

RemainingUrl/@{activity(activity_name).output.value.enrollment_number}